# Select <a> tags from databse and add rel="nofollow"

Tags: php, mysql, regex, select

I am not sure how to implement the following:

I have a database table "Posts" contains ID, Content, I have more than 20000 Posts in the Posts table, I would like to make mysql query to find all external  tags inside the Content record that don't have rel="nofollow" attribute, and then add rel="nofollow" and update the post.

Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Comment: you need to first try something out. Show us the code you have tried, then we'll help you from there.

Comment: I shall give u a hint, use stored procedure to make it easier and take a look at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Consider _not_ modifying the data, but instead 'fixing' the output _after_ fetching the data and before displaying it.

Comment: are you actually storing HTML markup in a database? If so, that isn't a good idea. HTML/PHP/MySQL are all totally different animals and should be treated as such.

Comment: Thank you @RickJames for your suggestion, you are absolutely right, I will go for this solution.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Posts contains HTML elements such as links, images etc, that need to be stored somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution on Stackoverflow, can't find the reference for it sorry. It worked for me.

```
$content = nofollow($content,'example.com');
function nofollow($html, $skip = null) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        "#(<a[^>]+?)>#is", function ($mach) use ($skip) {
            return (

                !($skip && strpos($mach[1], $skip) !== false) &&
                strpos($mach[1], 'rel=') === false
            ) ? $mach[1] . ' rel="nofollow">' : $mach[0];
        },
        $html
    );
}
```